# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\include\article.php on line 8

Tags: pdo

i am getting this error and was wondering how to fix it?
it is when i am trying to add my articles to the feed.

```
class Article {
    public function fetch_all() {
        global $pdo;


        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY `article_id` DESC");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }

    public function fetch_data($article_id) {
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $article_id);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    }
}

    ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [pdo - Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346186/pdo-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object)

Comment: You are getting what error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use that `global` attempt. That's not OOP design and one of the reasons whey your code fails. Instead make **sure** that you have been created `$pdo` so far and then pass it to the constructor of `Article`.

Further note the capability of the so called [`typehints`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). While using them you can enforce a special type for a method param. If you pass another value at runtime (like NULL or something else) PHP will throw an error:

```
    typehint-----------------|
public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
}
```

Example:

```
class Article {

    protected $pdo;

    // the type hint this makes !!SURE!! PDO is connected
    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function fetch_all() {

        $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY `article_id` DESC");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }

    public function fetch_data($article_id) {
        // note this:
        $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $article_id);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO($connectionString, $user, $pass);
$article = new Article($pdo);

var_dump($article->fetch_data($someId));
```

Comment: well i changed it to what you said then called it and i now get this error 
Notice: Undefined variable: connectionString in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\header.php on line 7


Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\header.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\header.php(7): PDO->__construct('', NULL, NULL) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\index.php(1): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\header.php on line 7

Comment: Think a moment. Are you really *unable* to answer *this* for yourself? ;)

Comment: it cant connect to the db?

Comment: `Undefined variable: connectionString` I have used this as a placeholder as I can't know your actual settings. You'll of course have to replace it with your actual settings. Damn! ;)

Comment: am stupid -.- lets see if i can fix it. just luring php and moved straight in to pdo :L

Comment: `and moved straight in to pdo` .. that's ok. Buy a O'Reilly!! if you are a beginner! good advice

Comment: Believe me. Buy a PHP book (or rent some) that's the best way to get into it. you'll see (and enjoy, because seeing progress) After finishing this start your own project

Answer (score 0):

`$pdo` is undefined by the time you are calling it. You need to create it first.