# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object.

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem when i enter login details i get this error

`Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Remake Login Page\Classes\Mysql.php on line 22`

Code of **Mysql.php**:

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/constants.php';

class Mysql {
private $conn;

function _construct() {
    $this->$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die 
                  ('There was a problem connecting to the database');
}

function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) {


    $query = "SELECT *
            FROM users
            WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
            LIMIT 1";


    if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
        $stmt->execute();


        if($stmt->fetch()) {
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        }
    }

}

}
```

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your constructor is wrong, should be __construct()

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346186/pdo-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object

Answer (score 4):

A constructor methods starts with double underscore. A method with a single underscore is just normal function name.

Try this:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('There was a problem connecting to the database');
}
```

Comment: what's the difference, double underscore?

Comment: it's a constructor. single underscore is just normal function name.

Answer (score 3):

Your construct function needs two underscores.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor should say `$this->conn` rather than `$this->$conn`.