# php - Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Tags: php, pdo

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/folder/public_html/includes/name.php on line 1768
```

This is the function:

```
function _FC_GET($typ, $data, $username){

            global $dbh;
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM stats_clicks WHERE typ=:typ AND user=:username AND data=:data LIMIT 1;");
            $stmt->bindParam(':typ', $typ);
            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
            try {
            $stmt->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                die( _OP_ERROR($e->getMessage(), __FILE__ ,__LINE__) );     
            }

            $QUERY_DAT = $stmt->fetchAll();
            return empty($QUERY_DAT['value']) ? 0 : $QUERY_DAT['value'];

        }
```

And this is line `1768`:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM stats_clicks WHERE typ=:typ AND user=:username AND data=:data LIMIT 1;");
```

I can't seem to find what is causing this. I use the `$dbh-prepare();` statement in other functions in the same file.

Comment: use var_dump($dbh) to see what's inside this object

Comment: Where is your `new PDO(..)` for `$dbh`?

Comment: `var_dump($dbh)` return `NULL`

Comment: variable $dbh is null that's the answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$dbh is not defined at that line. Check where you create the object $dbh if it is before the line 1768 or it is not in any condition which is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

[Look at here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346186/pdo-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object?rq=1)

Probably the cause of your connection.