# how to fix Call to a member function prepare() on string

Tags: php, pdo

I have been trying to fix this error: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on string in /home/...../lib/library.php on line 91`
 I have also check this link: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851)
and i don't seem to understand how to relate it to my problem at hand. Can anyone help? this is the script line affected:

```
public function Login($username, $password)
    {
        try {
            $db = DB();
            $query = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE (username=:username OR email=:username) AND password=:password");
            $query->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $enc_password = hash('sha256', $password);
            $query->bindParam("password", $enc_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();
            if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                return $result->user_id;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: `DB()` is not returning an instance of `PDO`. See http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346186/pdo-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
$db = DB();
```

If you were to `var_dump()` the `$db` variable you'd see it is equal to a string with a value of something like `DB` or `DB()`.

It should be:

```
$db = new DB();
```

Comment: Here DB is function not a class

Comment: Since db is a function here, how did you manage to solve the issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: If it is a function it needs to return an instance of a database class.